# Updating user-data for EC2 instances under an autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I want to modify / update the user-data for an EC2 instance. This is attached to an autoscaling cluster.

---

I understand that the instance needs to be `stopped` before the `user-data` can be updated. The problem I am facing is, when I stop the instance to update `user-data` autoscaler automatically brings a new instance back up.

---

Is there a way to update `user-data` without removing the EC2 instance from the autoscaling group?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For instances in an autoscaling group, the user data is generally updated by creating a new [launch configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/LaunchConfiguration.html) with your new user data.

Your AutoScaling group should be associated with a launch configuration already. There is an easy option to copy launch configurations from the AWS web console that will replicate all of your existing options. Simply find this launch configuration, copy it, and then replace the old user data before you save the new configuration.

[image]

Once the new launch configuration is created, apply it to your autoscaling group. You can begin using it immediately by increasing the desired size of the group to launch a new instance with the new configuration, and then [detach the old instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/detach-instance-asg.html) once you're satisfied that the new instance (and any hosted applications) are operational.

You can likewise use this method to change any property of a launch configuration without causing an interruption to your application.

**Further Resources:**

- [AWS Documentation - Creating a Launch Configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/create-launch-config.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only way can achieve this is by disabling autoscaling temporarily using programmatic invocation using aws sdk. 
You can restart the servers after the autoscaling is disabled.

(node API http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AutoScaling.html#suspendProcesses-property)

Comment: While it is true that this will solve OP's immediate problem, this misses the bigger picture that AutoScaling groups exist with the expectation that the instances aren't permanent.  OP would end up with the old user data again after the instance is cycled. Using suspendProcesses to make configuration tweaks to single instances in an AutoScaling group in this way will make it harder to troubleshoot issues as instances are cycled and is generally asking for trouble.

Comment: Agreed..I agree the instances have to ephemeral. I am just saying there are ways you can do this. And you never know whether in Op's case the instances are real throw away.